# Jquery EasyUI tabs icon

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have been working with Jquery's easyUI tabs to make tabs in my Sharepoint Online site. However, I have come across a minor inconvenience. In between the tabs is a little blue arrow that can be used to switch between the tabs, but it is unnecessary:

[image]

I dug through the web page inspector and found out that this is of class="tabs-icon"... So, I went into jquery.easyui.min.js to figure out what was causing this... Using the find function on "tabs-icon", the following popped up:

[image]

I'm not exactly sure how to fix this, but I found where it is being changed. Since jquery.easyUI is so huge, I was hoping someone would have experience and be able to guide me as to how to hide the blue arrows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering that the icons you want to hide have the class *tabs-icon* you should be able to hide them using CSS.

In your CSS file for EasyUI add:

```
.tabs-icon { display: none; }
```

or

```
.tabs-icon { visibility: collapse; }
```

The reason why (in my opinion) you should use CSS is 1. EasyUI is as you say large so editing the logic would be problematic and 2. CSS changes are easy to implement and easy to roll back

Comment: I love the idea, and I think it would work, however the siteassets library won't let me save over the file. It changes the modified date, but the changes aren't made to the file. any ideas?

Comment: Create a new CSS file and include it after the EasyUI CSS file. If included after it will overwrite the necessary places

Comment: what do you mean "include it after"?

Comment: Somewhere in your code you add EasyUI.js There is probably also a EasyUI.CSS file. You want to add your CUSTOM.CSS file after that.

Comment: ah ha! thank you, that worked just fine, appreciate it. Any idea why I can't just change the right CSS file to begin with? this could become tedious quickly

Comment: Don't know. Best practice in these cases is to usually have your own Custom CSS file that you use and update as required. That way if you need to roll back you can just delete that file. If this works can you please accept the answer?